# How to Combine Regex Lines into Single Regex to Remove Space and . in C#

Tags: c#, regex

How can I combine the following Regex into a single one to remove all spaces and periods in the file?  I figured out how to replace a single char, but not multiple characters in a single line.

```
        string testfile = @"C:\test\work\A Nightmare.On.Elm Street 1984.720p.BRRip.nfo";
        testfile = testfile.Substring(0, testfile.Length - 4);
        testfile = Regex.Replace(testfile, @"\.", "");
        testfile = Regex.Replace(testfile, @"\s", "");
```

Thanks!

Comment: `testfile = testfile.Replace(".", "")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex to use is `@"[\s\.]"`

```
testfile = Regex.Replace(testfile, @"[\s\.]", "");
```

Comment: dot has no special meaning inside `[]`. the extra slash is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
testfile = Regex.Replace(testfile, @"[.\s]", "");
```